# ImportError: No module named _mssql

Tags: python, pymssql

I'm running Python 2.7.2 on OS 10.8.5

Trying to use pymssql, but I get the following error:

```
  File "time_reporting.py", line 32, in <module>
    import pymssql
  File "/Users/xx/.virtualenvs/oracle/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymssql.py", line 30, in <module>
    import _mssql, types, string, time, datetime, warnings
ImportError: No module named _mssql
```

I've tried installing mssql with pip and brew only to be told that there's no package by that name.  The docs don't seem to cover installation.

EDIT:

When I try to `pip install pymssql` I get:

```
Downloading/unpacking pymssql
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pymssql
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Darwin'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('32bit', '')
    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('', '', '')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('', '')
    setup.py: Detected Darwin/Mac OS X.
        You can install FreeTDS with Homebrew or MacPorts, or by downloading
        and compiling it yourself.

        Homebrew (http://brew.sh/)
        --------------------------
        brew install freetds

        MacPorts (http://www.macports.org/)
        -----------------------------------
        sudo port install freetds

    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/oracle/build/pymssql/setup.py", line 181, in <module>
        if compiler.has_function('clock_gettime', libraries=['rt']):
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 808, in has_function
        objects = self.compile([fname], include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 616, in compile
        depends, extra_postargs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 412, in _setup_compile
        self.mkpath(os.path.dirname(obj))
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 931, in mkpath
        mkpath(name, mode, dry_run=self.dry_run)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dir_util.py", line 76, in mkpath
        "could not create '%s': %s" % (head, exc.args[-1]))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError: could not create 'var': Permission denied
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Darwin'

setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('32bit', '')

setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('', '', '')

setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('', '')

setup.py: Detected Darwin/Mac OS X.

    You can install FreeTDS with Homebrew or MacPorts, or by downloading

    and compiling it yourself.



    Homebrew (http://brew.sh/)

    --------------------------

    brew install freetds



    MacPorts (http://www.macports.org/)

    -----------------------------------

    sudo port install freetds



setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/oracle/build/pymssql/setup.py", line 181, in <module>

    if compiler.has_function('clock_gettime', libraries=['rt']):

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 808, in has_function

    objects = self.compile([fname], include_dirs=include_dirs)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 616, in compile

    depends, extra_postargs)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 412, in _setup_compile

    self.mkpath(os.path.dirname(obj))

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 931, in mkpath

    mkpath(name, mode, dry_run=self.dry_run)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dir_util.py", line 76, in mkpath

    "could not create '%s': %s" % (head, exc.args[-1]))

distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError: could not create 'var': Permission denied
```

So I try `brew install freetds` and I get:

`Warning: freetds-0.91 already installed, it's just not linked`

which at least makes sense, but I don't know how to fix it.

EDIT:  I've linked it, so `brew install freetds` gives the message that it's already installed, but `pip install pymssql` still gives the above error message.

EDIT:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments

pip uninstall MySQL-python
brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql --universal
pip install MySQL-python
```

Which now gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time_reporting.py", line 34, in <module>
    import pymssql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/oracle/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymssql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _dbversion
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/oracle/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymssql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/oracle/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymssql.so
```

Which I've had and fixed before but I don't remember what I did.

EDIT:

OK, I've re-installed the 32-bit oracle and forced Python to run the 32-bit version (I think.  I really have no idea what that last sentence means, but I think I've followed instructions correctly).

At any rate, here's my error message now:

```
  File "time_reporting.py", line 31, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/cx_Oracle.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/cx_Oracle.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/xxx/.python-eggs/cx_Oracle-5.1.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg-tmp/cx_Oracle.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/xxx/.python-eggs/cx_Oracle-5.1.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg-tmp/cx_Oracle.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Comment: I'm getting a little desperate here--I'm going to add a bounty when I can (eligible tomorrow) but if anyone can help sooner than that you have my word that I'll give you the bounty anyway!

Comment: What output do you get when you run `pip install pymssql`?

Comment: It's also somewhat strange that you are using a virtualenv. Is that intentional? Can you describe your project and its packaging setup? The answer may lay in there.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking.  I always use virtualenvs for any new project.  Will update question.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to install it somewhere outside your home directory where you dont have a permission to write. Maybe try to run `pip install pymssql` as a root :p

Comment: Have you tried a simple `brew link freetds`?

Comment: I get `Error: Could not symlink bin/tsql
Target /usr/local/bin/tsql
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm /usr/local/bin/tsql

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite freetds`

When I try that, I get:
`Linking /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.91... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/tsql
/usr/local/bin is not writable.`

Comment: I think I fixed the symlink (I _think_) because now brew install freetds just says it's already there, but `sudo pip install pymssql` still gives the same error as listed in the question.

Comment: You seem to be freely juggling the names MySQL and MSSQL (i.e. Microsoft SQL). Which one do you actually want to access?

Comment: What do you mean?  Might be a typo.  I'm trying to get pymssql installed, but in doing so I keep getting an internal import error about _mssql.

Comment: you are  compiling a 64 bit binary and linking to 32 bit  architecture  the oracle traceback shows you `x86_64`

Comment: Yeah--I forced Python to run with 32 bit and installed the 32 bit version of Oracle, which helped, but now I have some sort of problem with eggs.  I'm going to start fresh and will probably be back with new and exciting error messages soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran these as root:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Then had to do:

```
pip uninstall MySQL-python
brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql --universal
pip install MySQL-python
```

Not sure if it will be successful but it's at least a new error message.

Comment: You should move this via an edit to your question before it gets flagged as a non-answer and deleted.

Comment: @AaronHall Why? This seems like an answer, if not a definitive one.

Comment: Ok, I suppose I may have misunderstood.

Comment: No, I think you're right, actually.  I typed it as it was installing with my fingers crossed.

Comment: Why would installing MySql packages resolve issue with pymssql?

Answer (score 3):

I just hit this following code examples for handling exceptions with `pymssql`. To reference exceptions within `_mssql` library, you can now reference them through `pymssql._mssql`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ldconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig).

Taken from the man page:

> **ldconfig** creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/lib and /usr/lib).